# Generate list from string and display on page with VBS

Tags: html, windows, vbscript

I am trying to read a text file that contains some start characters but it can vary in the amount of elements indicating its cost and in the end the total sum. After generating the list must be shown on the page in the order they appear in `File.txt`.

`File.txt`: This document presents **ASCII** `FS`, `SI` and `CRLF` characters.

```
EchoFSSIB@ 20 BOX X   1 =    20CRLF
500 BOX X   1 =   500CRLF
        TOTAL =   520 USD
```

VBScript code:

```
Dim itr
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("c:\temp\text.txt")
If objFile.Size > 0 Then
    Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\text.txt", 1)
    strContents = objReadFile.ReadAll
    itr = strContents
    objReadFile.Close
End If

Dim scrns
scrns = Split(itr, Chr(32), -1, 1)
Dim s1
s1 = Replace(itr, scrns(0), "")

Dim scr
scr = Split(s1, Chr(13), -1, 1)

For count = 0 To UBound(scr)
    sss = sss + scr(count) & vbNewLine
Next
AmountBox.innerHtml = sss
```

Comment: What doesn't work as expected? What is the desired output? What is the actual output?

Comment: The current output contains the elements : 20 BOX X   1 =    20 500 BOX X   1 =   500 in the first line while in the second has TOTAL =   520 USD. The correct output should have one element in each line, 1)20 BOX X   1 =    20, 2)500 BOX X   1 =   500, 3)TOTAL =   520 USD

Comment: So, basically, you just need to remove the prefix `EchoFSSIB@ ` from the original file?

Comment: It is correct, I have exported the SSS output to a file and the format is correct but when viewing it on the page you see everything in one line. 'Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   'How to write file
   'outFile="c:\temp\Outsss.txt"
   'Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
   'objFile.Write sss
   'objFile.Close
  'AmountBox.innerhtml = sss

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prefix with a regular expression replacement like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
s1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\text.txt").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^.*?@"
s2 = re.Replace(s1, "")
```

`^.*?@` is the shortest match from the beginning of the string (`^`) up to and including the next `@` character.

Then split the string at newlines if you need the individual lines:

```
arr = Split(s2, vbNewLine)
```

Comment: I found the solution                                                                                    dim sss
  For count = 0 to Ubound(scr)
   sss = sss + scr(count)+ "<br>"
   'msgbox sss
   AmountBox.innerhtml = sss
  Next